# Getting alerts for a TCP LB whenever there's an unhealthy target?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-error-reporting

I am currently using an unmanaged TCP Load Balancer that has 3 target VMs, and to provide quick response I will need an alerting system whenever the healthy amount is not 3 out of 3 VMs

Is there a way to get alerts about this through e-mail, slack, or pagerduty in GCP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It's possible to create such an alert that will alert you when your one of the instances in your group stops working properly.**

Go your Unmanaged instance group details page and switch the tab to "Monitoring":

[image]

Click on **Create alerting policy** and you will see another panel:

[image]

At the bottom of this screen change the **Condition** to **is below** and **Threshold** to **3** as shown below.

[image]

You will find yourself at the Policy creation page:
[image]

Click **Next** and select desired notification channel, if you don't see any available click on [**Manage notification channels**](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options) and create one you want, it can be email, SMS, Slack and many others.

---

---

---

### Another approach is to create an alert triggered by logs.

First you need to create a health check (and [enable logging](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-logging)). Then you go to your load balancers settings and edit your backend service, in there you select the health check you created.

[image]

Then go to [Logs explorer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs) and select as a log resource your instance group. You will see in the [query editor](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries#getting-started) something like this:

`resource.type="gce_instance_group" resource.labels.instance_group_id="3863333883516335882" resource.labels.instance_group_name="hc-group-1"`

then add at the bottom this line: `jsonPayload.healthCheckProbeResult.healthState="UNHEALTHY"`

And then click "Run Query" which should result in a few logs that will contain logs that can be used to trigger an alert.

[image]

Now when you see the logs click on Actions and select "Create log alert":

[image]

You will see the window that will allow you to name the alert and select a proper channel to send notifications. I've just tested it (group of 2 VM's, after switching off either one of them triggered an alert) in a form of email:

[image]

Lastly - depending on the service you're running you can monitor many different services (in my case it was HTTP reply on port 80).

Comment: Unfortunately this is for instance count, not for healthcheck healthy count. I made 1 of my VMs "fail" the health check but it still shows 3

Comment: I've updated my answer to include another solution - it's a little lengthy but I found it to be more dependable.

Comment: Thanks, the second answer was the one I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to be of help and thanks for confirmation !